# Nearest Mating faces between two List of 3D planar faces using KD Tree

Tags: c#, c++, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

**Problem Statement:**
I have two lists of planar faces of two bodies.

- List1 {faceA1,faceA2,faceA3,faceA4.....faceAn}
- List2 {faceB1,faceB2,faceB3,faceB4.....faceBn}

I want to find which two faces in list1 and list2 are touching each other.
say faceA3 - faceB1 are mating / Touching each other. What is the fastest way to find the mating faces?
There is a possibility of finding multiple pairs of mating faces between two lists.

For Each planar face, I am having a face center (X, Y, Z) and Face normal (Vx, Vy, Vz)

I can create a for each loop run between two lists and compute the distance and get the mating pairs. But as the number of faces increases computation will take more time.

**Note:**

> Definition of mating faces is Two faces must be at zero distance and
> face normals must be opposite.

Comment: What is your precise definition of mating faces in this context? A distance of zero of the face centers and opposite normals?

Comment: Yes, my definition of mating faces is the distance between faces must be zero, and normals must be opposite.

Comment: Can you hash your faces by their centers, and compare normals by the faces with the same center? Worst-case is still quadratic, but average case is linear.

Comment: I kd-tree seem like a perfectly appropriate optimization strategy. Just storing centers and doing a closest point search would probably be sufficient. What is the actual question? How to implement a kd-tree? what optimizations would be appropriate? Also, mating faces according your your definition probably share vertices, so another approach would be to merge vertices, and check if the vertex-indices are the same.

Comment: @JonasH Yes, I do not know how to approach this using KD Tree. Implementation is what I am looking into.

Comment: There are plenty of articles how kd-trees work, and several .Net implementations. Most should have a "get all items within some distance" method. But stackoverflow is not a free code writing service, and library recommendations should go to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. So you should probably narrow your question to a precise problem.

Comment: @JonasH I will update the article with my implementation. And I will point out the correct problem statement. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I was not able to implement it. If anyone has suggestions please let me know.